# iPhone build which supports version 4.0 to 5.0 using Xcode 4.2

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar, xcode4.2, ios5

Hi i am working on iOS SDK5 with xcode 4.2 and i want to prepare a build which should be compatible with iOS 4.0 to 5.0 or at least 4.3 and 5.0

I have set the base sdk to 5.0 and deployment target to 4.0 but when i run the app in the iPhone 4 simulator my application crashes basically due to the code written below

```
[testNavigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook-navbar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

but the above code runs fine when i switch the iPhone simulator from 4 to 5 also i have tried setBackgroundColor but its not working so kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because -setBackgroundImage: was introduced in iOS 5, and Apple don't (usually) back port new API to older platforms as a rule. Anyway, you have two options:

```
if ([testNavigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:)]) {
  // do what you're currently trying
}
else {
  //find a compatible way to do it
}
```

or:

```
//find a compatible way to do it
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that method was added to iOS5, so it doesn't exist in iOS4. You need to do a runtime check to see if you're in iOS5, like the following:

```
if ([testNavigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics)]) {
    [testNavigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook-navbar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Now the problem is that you won't get the background in iOS4, so you'll have to find a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS version 4.x, you can always override the UINavigationBar drawRect.  Here is a posting on Stack Overflow on this very subject:

[Background image for navigation view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979750/background-image-for-navigation-view-iphone)