# Adding a background image to UINavigationBar covers the title

Tags: ios, background, uinavigationbar

I have successfully added a background image to my UINavigationBar with the following code:

```
    UIImageView *barView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"subHeader_lg.png"]];
    [calculatorBar addSubview:barView];

    [barView release];
```

However, with this method, the title of the view is covered by the image.

[image]

If I navigate further into the app, and then back, the title appears on top of the background image like so:

[image]

Any ideas how I can get the title to appear on top from the beginning?

I have tried pushing the `barView` to the back, but that makes it hidden behind everything else.

EDIT:

It seems that the custom draw function is the accepted answer, but I am unable to get the draw function to be called. I have this code at the bottom of my appdelegate.m file

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCustomDraw)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"subHeader_lg.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}

@end
```

Comment: Looks like this guy had a similar problem, but the answer was a bit more involved than the one you have. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979750/background-image-for-navigation-view-iphone/2046393#2046393

Answer (score 1):

When you call "addSubview" it adds it above any view that have already been added, thus covering the title.

What you want is

[calculatorBar insertSubview:barView atIndex:0];

However, this won't make it "stick" on subsequent pushes, so use the methods described at http://www.developers-life.com/custom-uinavigationbar-with-image-and-back-button.html for a better solution.

Also in iOS 5, Apple has added a built in way to customize the nav bar see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010906

Comment: Is the iOS5 solution backwards compatible?

Comment: No but here's another post that shows how to combine the two http://sebastiancelis.com/2009/12/21/adding-background-image-uinavigationbar/

Comment: When I try the custom draw function, it is never even called.

Comment: Do you have any advice for why the custom draw function wouldn't be working?

Answer (score 1):

To set the background image on your navigation bar, use the following.

On iOS 5.x, use 
[calculatorBar setBackgroundImage: barView.image forBarMetrics: 0];

On iOS 4.x use
calculatorBar.layer.contents = (id)barView.image.CGImage;

Comment: I'm trying to support all iOS versions, what about prior to iOS 4.0

Comment: The following should work on iOS 3.x too.

calculatorBar.layer.contents = (id)barView.image.CGImage;

Comment: For some reason my compiler is not recognizing the contents property on the CALayer object

Comment: Try to add #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>