# Image as rightBarButtonItem from URL

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I try to assign an image loaded via

```
[UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl]];
```

to my navigationbar.
Here is what i have:

```
   //Loading Image from Url and adding it to navigationbar
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://someurl.com/%@.gif",imageId];
    NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl]];
    UIButton* button = (UIButton *) myImage;
    UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonItem;
```

This works as long as i take a local image and allocate the image view like this:

```
UIButton* button = (UIButton *) [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myLocalImage.png"]];
```

The error i get is:
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage _setAppearanceIsInvalid:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6876df0'

Anybody can help? (Or is this too nasty of a hack anyway?)
Thanks a lot!

Ps: heres the original question for the adding image to navigation bar: [how to display an image in the navigation bar of an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844416/how-to-display-an-image-in-the-navigation-bar-of-an-iphone-application)

**Edit:**
Theres an error in the code:
Should be like this i guess:

```
UIButton* button = (UIButton *) [[UIImageview alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
```

Anyway, i dont get an error anymore now, but the image does not appear...

Comment: use a button as the customView instead of an image view

Comment: Have a look at my answer and tell me if you have problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work asynchronously

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton alloc] init];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button]; 
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;

__block UIImage *image;
// create a dispatch queue to download your image asynchronously
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("image downloader", NULL);
// show network activity indicator
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
 dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
        image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl]];
        // dispatch to the main queue
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // set your button's image
                [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            });
        }
});
    dispatch_release(downloadQueue);
// hide network activity indicator
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Had this code in a seperate thread and i guess this is not working after the view is already loaded. If i put it plain to vieDidLoad then it works...

You'll get enlighted as soon as you post here... ^^

Comment: maybe someone can answer how it would still be possible to load the image asynchronous?